# Magento simple product with custom options and different stocks

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, product, configurable

I have a problem in finding a solution for our store. We are selling shoes with different colors and sizes. Each product has a different sku based on color and size and different stock.

Until now all is simple, I can use configurable products but I want to have all options visible in category list as a separate product.

For eg.: in flats category I have a product with 2 different colors and I want to display them separately and when I choose one of them there I want to have the options of other colors and sizes.

Is there a solution or a module that I can use?

Comment: I wonder if you can have simple products in more than one configurable product and so use that as a mechanism?

Comment: So you recommend me to duplicate the configurable product with the same simple products, right?

Comment: Duplicate is the wrong word. Have, say, 3 configurable products, flat red shoes, flat blue shoes, all flat shoes. But I don't know if it would work. It shouldn't take long to try. If you do try it, please let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is in the description, Configurable product would suit your situation better. For each configurable product, you can have multiple simple product with different colour and sizes. And you can change the visibility attribute of the simple product to make it show up in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks, that is an option. Please take a look at this shop. They are listing products by color attribute and if yu inspect element you can see that the link to product have the color parameter. http://www.aigle.com/en_fr/woman/shoes.html#